# Add employees as followers when sales quotations was confirmed

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I created an automated_action, which should add specific employees as followers dynamically. The fields are already existent in the model. But my automated action doesnt work at atll, no new followers will be added :

[image]

```
record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=[record.x_studio_overall_lead.id, record.x_studio_technical_lead.id, record.x_studio_overall_deputy.id,record.x_studio_technical_deputy.id])
```

Added : If the customer is set those employees will be set in the sales order in a hidden page :
[image]

Via studio I created a new page in the form view of the sales quotations and related fields to the those employees which are set in the contacts addon. SO I dont understand why the automated action doesnt trigger anything, because I even dont have to access another model or to give a link to the fields.

Comment: Can you add at least one of the field's definition?

Comment: I hope its better to understand now

Comment: Partly. Which model is behind those fields: `res.users` or `res.partner`?

Comment: ""hr.employee"" is behind the 4 fields

Comment: That won't work with `message_subscribe`. You need partners or partner IDs for that. If you have `user_id` set on the employes you could for example use `record.x_studio_overall_lead.user_id.partner_id.id`.

Comment: Thankn you very much for your help. Would you mind explaining me why I coudnt use employee_ids ?

Comment: Is there an error message? Is `user_id` filled?

Comment: Because employee_ids is using model `hr.employee` and the message system (messages and followers) is using model `res.partner` as base. Every user in the system has a partner anyways so employees with users in Odoo will work like charm. But employees without user is another story.

Comment: Your solution is working without any errors. Thank you very much for your help